# Set Jupyter Lab password encrypted with SHA 256

Tags: python, ubuntu, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, sha

I am currently running a Jupyter lab service on my Ubuntu 18.04 server. I have set the password on my lab using the following command:

```
$ jupyter notebook --generate-config
$ jupyter notebook password
```

It responds with the following output:

```
[NotebookPasswordApp] Wrote hashed password to /Users/you/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.json
```

After that I add the config settings in .jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py file as follows:

```
c.NotebookApp.password = u'sha1:bcd259ccf...<my hashed password here>'
```

What I want is to get SHA 256 hashed password instead of SHA 1 purely because of the additional level of encryption offered by SHA 256 hash due to its bigger length.

I am wondering if there's a way to make this possible? Currently I have tried several options and none of them seem to work.

Comment: For newer versions see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76943786/12892)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `notebook.auth` module offers a function called `passwd`. The second argument is an algorithm. You can use that function to obtain a SHA 256 hashed password.

```
"""Parameters
----------
passphrase : str
    Password to hash.  If unspecified, the user is asked to input
    and verify a password.
algorithm : str
    Hashing algorithm to use (e.g, 'sha1' or any argument supported
    by :func:`hashlib.new`, or 'argon2').

Returns
-------
hashed_passphrase : str
    Hashed password, in the format 'hash_algorithm:salt:passphrase_hash'."""

from notebook.auth import passwd

my_password = "spam-and-eggs"

hashed_password = passwd(passphrase=my_password, algorithm='sha256')

print(hashed_password)
```

OUTPUT: `sha256:128c5116bc40:94cfe1eef8703b657a7ef28af741fa05465c7a7355645a65040bd51bccc6039b`

Comment: Is it also possible to create a password without the jupyter python lib?

Answer (score 1):

#### Easily use the .conf file guidance:

```
from notebook.auth import passwd
passwd("somepassword")
```

Output: `'argon2:$argon2id$v=19$m=102.....'`

Then put the entire string in your .conf file