# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'notebook.auth'

Tags: python, jupyter

I am setting up Jupyter notebook environment from remote server. When I import `notebook.auth` it report error like this :

```
>>> from notebook.auth import passwd
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'notebook.auth'
```

My jupyter parameter are like this :

```
Selected Jupyter core packages...
IPython          : 8.2.0
ipykernel        : 6.25.0
ipywidgets       : 8.1.0
jupyter_client   : 8.1.0
jupyter_core     : 5.3.0
jupyter_server   : 2.7.2
jupyterlab       : 4.0.5
nbclient         : 0.8.0
nbconvert        : 7.2.9
nbformat         : 5.9.2
notebook         : 7.0.2
qtconsole        : 5.4.3
traitlets        : 5.7.1
```

Does anyone know how to fix the problem? I have already tried with pip install jupyter. It doesnot work at all.

Thanks,

Comment: This must already have happened before, try looking better around at stackoverflow

Comment: Is it this `from jupyter_server.auth import passwd; passwd()`

Answer (score 6):

From Jupyter Notebook 7, use the [`jupyter_server.auth`](https://jupyter-server.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/jupyter_server.auth.html#jupyter_server.auth.security.passwd) module instead of `notebook.auth`:

```shell
$ jupyter server password
Enter password:  ****
Verify password: ****
[JupyterPasswordApp] Wrote hashed password to /Users/you/.jupyter/jupyter_server_config.json
```

or ipython:

```python
from jupyter_server.auth import passwd
passwd()
```

References:

- [GitHub issue 7015 - Missing notebook.auth submodule?](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/7015)
- [Official documentation for "Automatic Password setup"](https://jupyter-server.readthedocs.io/en/latest/operators/public-server.html#automatic-password-setup)

Comment: lifesaver! chatGPT, claude, Gemini all gives the old notebook.auth method haha.

Answer (score 1):

I also have this problem, maybe the notebook 7.0.x have removed the 'auth'. I solved the problem by pip install notebook==6.5.5. I didn't try other visions, it may also work to install 6.x.x.